# pdf files not uploading into the server in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Hi Here i am using CActiveFrom fileField to upload the file in the server but the pdf files not saving remaining all the extensions are saving here is my controller code to save the file

### controller

```
 if(isset($_POST['Uploadinfo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Uploadinfo'];


            $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageId');


            $model->imageId=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageId');


            $valid = $model->validate();


            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
            $serverTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

            if(!empty($file->name) && $valid)
            {

                $modelFileLocation->filename = microtime() . $file->name;
                $modelFileLocation->orgfilename = $file->name;
                $modelFileLocation->type = 1;
                $modelFileLocation->createdOn = $serverTime;
                $modelFileLocation->lastModifiedBy = 'lecturer';

                $valid = $modelFileLocation -> validate();


                $modelFileLocation->deptId = $_POST['Uploadinfo']['departmentId'];
                print_r($file);

                if ($modelFileLocation->save())
                {
                    $file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageId');
                    print_r($modelFileLocation);
                print_r($file);
                die();  

                $model->userId = $_POST['Uploadinfo']['userId'];
                $model->imageId = $modelFileLocation->id;
                $model->departmentId = 1;
                $model->createdOn = $serverTime;
                $model->lastModifiedBy = 'lecturer';

                    if ($model->save())
                    {

                        $modeldocumentinfo->property = $file->type;
                        $modeldocumentinfo->fileName = $modelFileLocation->filename;
                        $modeldocumentinfo->creator = 'lecturer';
                        $modeldocumentinfo->lastUploadedOn = $serverTime;
                        $modeldocumentinfo->uploadId = $model->id;
                        $modeldocumentinfo->viewers = 0;

                        $modeldocumentinfo->save();

                        $file->saveAs('uploads/files/' . $modelFileLocation->filename);
                            print_r($file);
            die();
                        //Yii::app()->user->setFlash('uploadsuccess', "File Uploaded Successfully...");
                        $this->redirect(array('lmaterialitview'));
                    }
                }
```

in above code i print the instance of file before and after the $modelFileLocation model saving before this model is saving the file instance is getting but after this saving the model the file instance getting empty

here is the instance code

### instance message

```
 CUploadedFile Object ( [_name:CUploadedFile:private] => example.pdf [_tempName:CUploadedFile:private] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4BB.tmp [_type:CUploadedFile:private] => application/pdf [_size:CUploadedFile:private] => 205374 [_error:CUploadedFile:private] => 0 [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )
```

and in the second print_r() it is disappering but for remaining extensions it is getting appear and saving

Answer (score 0):

just set the $deleteTempFile argument to false

```
$file->saveAs('uploads/files/' . $modelFileLocation->filename, false);
```